# Sendmail "Connection refused by mail.example.com" when attempting to send emails

Tags: sendmail, linode

I'm trying to have a virtually hosted PHP site send emails to a particular Gmail address when the site's contact form is correctly filled out and submitted.  Unfortunately, nothing is being sent out.  In `/var/log/mail.log` I have numerous instances of things like this:

```
Jul 31 16:38:51 picus sm-mta[28576]: v6SL4xII018234: to=<person@gmail.com>,
delay=2+23:33:52, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=38910659, 
relay=mail.example.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred:Connection refused by 
mail.example.com.
```

I'm completely new to handling an email server, and simply wanted to use Sendmail since it's built into the distro I'm using and Swiftmailer supports it, so I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

My `sendmail.mc` file looks like:

```
divert(-1)dnl
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $Sendmail: debproto.mc,v 8.14.4 2014-10-02 17:54:06 cowboy Exp $
#
# Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
# cf/debian/sendmail.mc.  Generated from sendmail.mc.in by configure.
#
# sendmail.mc prototype config file for building Sendmail 8.14.4
#
# Note: the .in file supports 8.7.6 - 9.0.0, but the generated
#       file is customized to the version noted above.
#
# This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
# If you modify this file, you will have to regenerate /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# by running this file through the m4 preprocessor via one of the following:
#       * make   (or make -C /etc/mail)
#       * sendmailconfig
#       * m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# The first two options are preferred as they will also update other files
# that depend upon the contents of this file.
#
# The best documentation for this .mc file is:
# /usr/share/doc/sendmail-doc/cf.README.gz
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
divert(0)dnl
#
#   Copyright (c) 1998-2005 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
#  This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`$Id: sendmail.mc, v 8.14.4-8 2014-10-02 17:54:06 cowboy Exp $')
OSTYPE(`debian')dnl
DOMAIN(`debian-mta')dnl
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
undefine(`confHOST_STATUS_DIRECTORY')dnl        #DAEMON_HOSTSTATS=
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
dnl #
dnl # General defines
dnl #
dnl # SAFE_FILE_ENV: [undefined] If set, sendmail will do a chroot()
dnl #   into this directory before writing files.
dnl #   If *all* your user accounts are under /home then use that
dnl #   instead - it will prevent any writes outside of /home !
dnl #   define(`confSAFE_FILE_ENV',             `')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Daemon options - restrict to servicing LOCALHOST ONLY !!!
dnl # Remove `, Addr=' clauses to receive from any interface
dnl # If you want to support IPv6, switch the commented/uncommentd lines
dnl #
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Be somewhat anal in what we allow
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',dnl
`needmailhelo,needexpnhelo,needvrfyhelo,restrictqrun,restrictexpand,nobodyreturn,authwarnings')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Define connection throttling and window length
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `15')dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`10m')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Features
dnl #
dnl # use /etc/mail/local-host-names
FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The access db is the basis for most of sendmail's checking
FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The greet_pause feature stops some automail bots - but check the
dnl # provided access db for details on excluding localhosts...
FEATURE(`greet_pause', `1000')dnl 1 seconds
dnl #
dnl # Delay_checks allows sender<->recipient checking
FEATURE(`delay_checks', `friend', `n')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If we get too many bad recipients, slow things down...
define(`confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE',`3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Stop connections that overflow our concurrent and time connection rates
FEATURE(`conncontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
FEATURE(`ratecontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If you're on a dialup link, you should enable this - so sendmail
dnl # will not bring up the link (it will queue mail for later)
dnl define(`confCON_EXPENSIVE',`True')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Dialup/LAN connection overrides
dnl #
include(`/etc/mail/m4/dialup.m4')dnl
include(`/etc/mail/m4/provider.m4')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Default Mailer setup
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl

dnl # Masquerading options
FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`debian')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
```

I think it may be a DNS issue, however, as I cannot connect to the server via telnet on port 25.  The port seems to be open in my iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -nv --line-numbers

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       46.7.84.73           0.0.0.0/0           
2     4047  304K fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
3     4926  376K fail2ban-recidive  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4     4048  304K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
5      213 26142 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
6        0     0 REJECT     all  --  !lo    *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
7        2    60 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW icmptype 8
8       26  1456 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW
9       14   816 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW
10      16   932 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW
11       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587 state NEW
12       4   240 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 state NEW
13    4903  378K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
14     114  7692 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
15     130 13980 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       46.7.84.73           0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
3        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 129 packets, 11501 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
2      105 15686 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25

Chain fail2ban-recidive (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     4926  376K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       10  1276 REJECT     all  --  *      *       91.197.232.103       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2     4038  303K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The result of `$ netstat -tan | grep LISTEN | grep 127.0.0.1 | sort` is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

But the result of `$ netstat -tan | grep 25` is

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Is there a reason why it's not showing up in the first group?

Comment: Do you have `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`? Can you modify it and recompile it into sendmail.cf?  I can try to answer  "general sendmail" question.

Comment: I've posted my version of the file.  I think this may be more of a DNS issue than anything.  This is for a virtually hosted site on Linode, and as such, this domain doesn't have a reverse DNS entry.

Comment: if the sendmail service is "running" but port 25 is closed depite firewalls being "opened", it's clearly a configuration problem.

Comment: when you do a "netstat -an | grep 25", do you see the port "listening" ? (if you see it listening, it means you have a firewall issue, or routing issue)

Comment: Edited my post with it for better formatting

Comment: I do have the MX record setup in my DNS: mail.example.com

Comment: I've also edited in my full iptables setup

Comment: If it's just for outgoing email from that server, then firewall shouldn't be an issue, and you won't be able to telnet to it from any remote server. YOu can see from your netstat that it is only listening on localhost ip

Comment: I think it might be a Swiftmailer issue.  I've been receiving emails from the server with OSSEC and fail2ban, but looking through the log, they simply use localhost.  For some reason, the website, which uses Swiftmailer, is attempting to route it through `mail.example.com`.  I do have an MX record with that name, but it's weird that it's not defaulting to localhost even though that's what I put for a value in the config.

Comment: I've added some more info, if anyone is interested in checking it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined that the issue is really a programming issue, specifically with Swiftmailer.  Other services on my server (OSSEC, fail2ban) have no problems sending out emails, and I can even successfully send out an email using Swiftmailer when accessing it through the Symfony console.  It's only when my controller code creates an email and sends it to the mail spool that the issue comes up.

To that end, I'm going to answer/close this question.  If anyone knows Swiftmailer well enough to help me, I have a [post at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468446/symfony-3-3-and-swiftmailer-mail-created-and-sent-by-controller-deferred-by-se) about it.

Comment: Have you checked `postqueue -p` (`mailq`) output?

Comment: I'm not using Postfix